# Unable to modify Nginx.conf

Tags: javascript, nginx, server, nginx-reverse-proxy, nginx-config

I install Nginx through Homebrew using the below command

```
brew install nginx
```

It got successfully installed and I even tried running it on the default port 8080 using the below command

```
nginx
```

and that too worked.

Now when I ran the below command to modify the file

```
vim /usr/local/etc/nginx/nginx.conf
```

the file opened but I was not able to edit that...why is that happening. Please help me out.

Thanks in advance

Comment: How about `sudo`?

Comment: its working ....iam now able to modify...how to save the changes

Comment: got it ....Thanks @Jax-p